# Draw using graph coordinates in android

Tags: android, android-layout, graph, zooming, android-mapview

In my android app, I want to draw circles and then have to find their intersection points. And then i need to draw the lines between the intersection points which i got. I know how to implement this logic but dont know where to draw like graph.

I tried to draw this on mapview using Geopoints, considered lattitude as "x" axis and longitude as "y"axis. Its not good enough as I expected.(Sometimes lines disappear when zooming).

Which feature of Android facilitate this? Guide me to implement this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a custom view.  Custom views allow you to draw to a Canvas.  Canvas has functions like drawLine and drawCircle.  It takes x,y coordinates, with 0,0 being the upper left corner and x and y growing bigger as you go right and down.  If you don't want 0,0 to be the upper left, you can always use some basic algebra to translate it wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In custom view can i create a graph to draw lines are circles? Because i dont want to draw on screen using screen coordinates.